# Android 12 custom splash screen with background image

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-12

Can we use a background image drawable instead of a background single color. For other OS versions we had background image. Now how to set the exact same on Android 12? Any workaround possible?

Comment: It seems that it's not possible starting Android 12 [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74583104/2476688)